# How can files be opened by name in shared storage with native libraries without all files permission?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-permissions

We are writing a C++ app that is cross compiled for Android. This app uses native libraries (namely [gdal](https://gdal.org/) and [Qt](https://qt.io)) to read and write files.

These files often have references to each other (e.g. a xml file, referencing other files next to it; or shapefiles, where multiple files have a common base name). The above mentioned libraries need to be able to open files by path (`fopen(name)`) to get access to all information.

Common use cases are:

- download a zip file using a browser, unzip it using an file manage (e.g. amaze) and open the contents in our app
- use a file sharing app like nextcloud, syncthing, ... to sync a folder. The files in this folder are then edited by our app.

Since API level 30 [Google PlayStore restricts file access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files) and only allows unrestricted direct file access in an specific app-specific directory.

In shared folders (e.g. the Download folder, root folders in external storage devices, etc.) only a subset of file types is accessible through direct file access.

The [Acess media files from shared storage documentation](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=en) mentions

> If you don't have any storage-related permissions, you can access files in your app-specific directory, as well as media files that are attributed to your app, using the File API.

*Media files* in our tests include images, videos, ... but not the file types required here (.dbf, .shp, .qgs).

There is also the storage access framework where a [DocumentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider) can be used to stream data of individual files and intents like [OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) these will however generate access via URI which is not compatible with native `fopen(name)` calls.

The only option we found capable of opening files by name (through native labraries) is to use the [all files permission (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files). This works well but needs to be whitelisted to be published on Google Play Store.

Google support suggests using the system file picker (and sometimes extends the suggestion to "or other privacy friendly approaches").

Q: *If your libraries could work with paths before then they still can. Where is it that the problem starts?*

A: On Android 11, without a `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, what we have seen in our multiple tests is that directly opening non-media files in shared locations via their path strings is not working anymore.
The file opening fails.
We have also noticed that doing a directory listing (using Qt APIs) only shows media file extensions, skipping all other types.

How is it possible to open files by file path (string) in shared locations with native libraries without the all files permission (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)?

Comment: You are talking about libraries AND file sharing apps. It's unclear to me which of the two have problems using file names or file descriptors.

Comment: Further it is unclear to me which app downloaded the zip file. Your app? Or how? As i do not understand your problem. If your libraries could work with paths before then they still can. Where is it that the problem starts?

Comment: File sharing and downloading are mentioned to describe the workflow a user normally has prior to using our app to view/edit those files in-place. The focus here is our app which uses native libraries.

Comment: You are so unclear. No to the point answers. `what we have seen in our multiple tests is that directly opening non-media files via their path strings is not working anymore. ` Of course that still works if you have read permission. But now adays your app has no read permission if those paths are of files created by other apps. You are not mentioning the real problem..

Comment: To come back at the title of your post: `Is it possible to open files by name with native libraries without all files permission?` Yes using a file system path is possible if the files belong to your app.

Comment: Following the context given in the workflow that they are created by different apps, these files do not belong to our app. Still it is a user requirement to open them. If "How can we acquire complete file permission access (opening of non-media file types via their file path strings) for a given folder?" is the better question to ask, that is a very valid interpretation of it.